# Java class not found error when opening Citrix

Tags: firefox, java, citrix

When I try to open Citrix,I am getting below error. Please advise.

Ubuntu : 11.04
Firefox : 7.0.1
Sun Java Version :1.6.0_26

---

```
load: class com.citrix.ConnectionCenter not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.citrix.ConnectionCenter
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:250)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:687)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3025)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1498)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.citrix.ConnectionCenter
```

Comment: Are you still looking for help or have you solved this problem?